# How to generate a list which contains dictionaries?

Tags: python

I would like to generate a list that contains dictionaries. In each dictionary, the key is fixed, and the value is fed in from a loop.

The format is below:

```
mylist = [{'name': 'test101', 'status': '30'}, {'name': 'test102', 'status': '90'}]
```

However a `for loop` only traverses the list, which is not what I want.  How can I generate a list of dictionaries?

```py
mylist = []
for name in mylist:
    status = random()
    mylist.append("name")
    mylist.append(name)
    mylist.append("status")
    mylist.append(status)
```

Comment: What function is `random()`?

Comment: A for loop doesn't generate a list. It *traverses*
 it.

Comment: You only need to append **one** item to your list on each iteration through the loop: a dictionary

Comment: Note that `list = []` is an empty list, so `for name in list` will never execute its body.

Comment: You should avoid using `list` as a variable name because it is already used as a builtin name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following code to achieve your needs:

```py
result_list = []
for name in names_list:
    status = random()
    obj = {'name': name, 'status': status}
    result_list.append(obj)
```

In the code you provided in each iteration you are pushing 4 different items in the list, however in the code above I am creating a dictionary (such as the one you represented in your answer) and appending it into the list.

Other ways of creating this list exist, such as using the `dict()` built-in, or using [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) such as follows:

```py
result_list = [ {'name': name, 'status': random()} for name in names_list ]
```

#### Disclaimer

- You are using the `list` keyword as your variable's name. You have to consider that declaring a variable with such a name is not recommended, as `list` is a Python built-in function and the reference to it will be lost.
- The code you provided is in fact iterating over the `list` variable, which is in fact an empty list and so this would result in the same list (as there are no items in which to iterate over).

Comment: How did you even understand the question. But you have an empty list, and list is already a built-in.

Comment: One problem `for name in list` is iterating over the same list that you are appending to.

Comment: `list` is a reserved word.  May I suggest using something else in your example.

Comment: It might be clearer if you have a separate `name_list` and `dict_list`.

Comment: Thank you cariesgg97, your input is exactly what I want !